# Type a URL without it becoming an anchor link

Tags: support, editor, hyperlinks

Whenever I write some URL in thr editor, this automatically becomes a URL. For example, http://prateek.co.in.

But I don't want this; I want it to appear just as plain text. How can I achieve this?

Edit:
Trying out the newly learned feature here - http://prateek.co.in

Comment: You can also make it inline code by wrapping with backticks e.g. `http://prateek.co.in` but Doorknob's answer is much better.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Escape a character with a backslash:

```
http:\//www.google.com
```

http://www.google.com

Comment: Not working as expected, see... [http://i41.tinypic.com/19wocp.png](Pic)

Comment: Nice one, the preview show it with the escape character but it actually works.

Comment: @PrateekSingla the preview has a bug but it does work.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd- Why is it not working for me! :(

Comment: @PrateekSingla: Did you read ShaWizDowArd's comment? Even though it appears broken in the preview window, when you post it, it does actually work.

Comment: @Matt Let me check that over here - http:\//www.google.com

Comment: @Matt - It didn't worked out, I guess.

Comment: @PrateekSingla it works only in posts, for comments there's no choice but add backticks as I described above as comment to your question..

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - How can I test that without getting Downvotes for my question?

Comment: @PrateekSingla have 10 reputation points here on Meta (you need one more upvote) then post new answer in the [sandbox](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3122/152859). Until then you can edit your own question here.

Comment: @PrateekSingla: just edit your question to try it out.

Comment: @Mat Thanks. It worked!

Comment: This doesn't work anymore. At least not in preview.

Comment: @Himanshu: Isn't that what the previous comments said?

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum: I think I need some coffee now.