# Preview for links differs from rendered HTML

Tags: bug, editor, markdown-preview

When I try to escape a URL (using a backslash), to prevent it being automatically hyperlinked, the preview is rendered like so;

[image: Bug]

However, upon posting it appears like this;

[image]

I.e. the preview differs from what is actually show in the rendered HTML;

Comment: Why the backslash?

Comment: @Bart - I don't want this to be parsed as an anchor link, thats why...

Comment: It'll look fine once you saved the edit

Comment: Why is this a bug then - a malformed URL should render like that? If you enclose a URL in a code block (backticks) it will not be clickable.

Comment: @Oded- What if I want this to be rendered just like plain text and not like the pre formatted code.

Comment: @Oded preview should show exactly how the post will look like once sent. It's not, hence this is indeed bug in preview. Maybe this whole trick is a bug, but still... there is a bug, somewhere. :)

Answer (score -3):

The backslash appears **only in the preview**. It'll look fine once you post your answer but - and this is the important difference - the URL won't be rendered as link, only regular text.

Comment: So, Isn't it a bug?

Comment: Ain't a bug in my book. It's the feature [Doorknob told you about](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182690/type-a-url-without-it-becoming-an-anchor-link)

Comment: That's not the point here.

Comment: @djf Feature is that you can do so.., but preview does not work fine is a bug I guess...